# Exception error minesweeper game

Tags: java, awt, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

Hello I am currently attempting to create a minesweeper game, i have my gui and am using a 2d array in order to store whether or not a location has a mine, however when i attempt to have the game end for clicking on a mine using this code:

```
if (board[row][col] == 1) {
    return GameStatus.Lost; }  
else {
    return GameStatus.Continue;
 }
```

I get error as

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at Game.getGameStatus(Game.java:55)
at MineSweeperPanel$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(MineSweeperPanel.java:71)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: better if you provide the code here... edit your question and provide the code where array is defined and loop where you are adding data in that array.... without that we won't be able to help...

Answer (score 0):

Check the bounds that you call in `row` and `col`. If, for example, you have 25 rows and columns and you're referring to `board[25][25]`, this is past the bounds of the array. Although the overall *size* of the number of rows is 25, in the array the indices will go from `0` to `25-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Array Index Out Of Bounds means that your array has (say) 10 elements in it, but you've tried to access (say) the 11th element - it just doesn't exist.

Sanity check - arrays are indexed starting from 0, are your values in `row` and `col` indexed from 1?

Answer (score 0):

### When it occurs?

Out of bounds exception is occurred when you try to access an array with index that exceeded its length. maximum index of a java array is (length -1)
for example:

```
String [] stringArray = new String[10];
stringArray[10]
// the code above will produce an out of bounds exception, because the it bigger than length -1, which is 10 - 1 = 9.
```

If you don't know the size or length of an array, you can know it from `stringArray.length`.

### How to handle it?

You should make sure that your program doesn't access an array with index bigger than length - 1.
example:

```
for(int i=0;i<stringArray.lenght;i++) {
    //write your code here
}
```

the above code will guarantee that `stringArray` will never be accessed beyond its maximum index.

### Your Case

In your case, you must have defined the array limit and trying to access the data of array which is out of range of defined limit.

Also read [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-exception/index-out-bound-exception.shtml) for more info...

[Example of 2d array having out of bound exception](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/loops-control-statements/10173-out-bounds-error-2d-irregular-array-integers.html)